# MongoDB projection ignores high level properties if nested one present

Tags: mongodb

My document structure is,

```
{
  _id: '',
  l1: {
    l21: {
      l31: ''
    },
    l22: {
      l32: ''
    }
  }
}
```

When I do project like `{'l1.l21.l31': 1, 'l1': 1}`, only `l1.l21.l31` got projected. The second one `l1` is got ignored, ie `l22` is not getting projected. Is there a way to avoid this kind of situation? I have an API which generate project fields based on client request. So, I cannot ask client to include only high level property when coming to nested case. Can we include any switch or something to not ignore like the above one?

Comment: Have you tried `{'l1.l21.l31': 1, 'l1.l22': 1}` ?

Comment: Yes @Karlen. I know that will work. If I have l33 to l99, it'll be hard giving all of them in select, right?

Comment: OK, in your question you mean that once there is a case like `l1` then the `l1.l21.l31` shod be ignored rather than the `l1` and in this case it will return the all nested fields of `l1`, right?

Comment: Exactly @Karlen